# Change or show privacy setting when using Feed Dialog

Tags: ios, facebook, feed

My app is posting to facebook with help of Feed Dialog, but unfortunately public audience of my post is only-me. When I'm trying to set privacy key in publish params for friends visibility:

```
 NSMutableDictionary *params =
    [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
     @"my app_id", @"app_id",
     @"my app name", @"name",
     @"some text.", @"caption",
     @"some more text.", @"description",
     @"web site link", @"link",
     @"some picture link", @"picture",
     @"ALL_FRIENDS", @"privacy",
     nil];
```

So when adding  @"ALL_FRIENDS", @"privacy", I receive an error in Dialog window when I try to publish: Error100 (I'm using incorrect privacy parameter).
So my question is how can I change this parameter or how can I let user to change it Feed dialog window (I'm using 3.5 facebook SDK).
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so what have I done to solve the problem:

1.I'm closing any active session when my app launches:

```
FBSession* currentSession = [FBSession activeSession];
if(currentSession) {
    [currentSession close];
}
```

2.Establishing new connection with friends as **default audience**

```
 [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"]
                                   defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                      allowLoginUI:YES
                                 completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
                                     if (!error && status == FBSessionStateOpen) {
                                         [self publishWithWebDialog];
                                     }else{
                                         NSLog(@"error");
                                     }
                                 }];
```

3.Calling method for publishing with Feed Dialog:

```
[self publishWithWebDialog];
```

The fun part starts when application is launched for the second time :) There is no need to press all that OK buttons and application just opens Feed dialog, by the way this approach also fixes the problem with deleting application in Facebook from users Account Settings - > Apps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you'll be able to override the Only Me setting that the user has set in their privacy settings. In general, to get past the dialog error, you can try:

```
@"{'value': 'ALL_FRIENDS'}", @"privacy",
```

I know this setting works with Graph API posts (ex: me/feed) when I set the privacy level to something less than what the user has specified to be their ceiling. So if their ceiling is Only Me, the post will show up as Only Me. If their ceiling is Friends and I set the privacy to SELF then I get a post that's Only Me.

You can consider using the new Share Dialog (in 3.5.2). It allows the user to select their privacy. The Feed Dialog windows does not have a privacy selector.

For a comparison of the different share options, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/share-dialogs-ios-sdk/

Comment: @C Abernathy: Is it possible to request `Friends` audience before posting? I've seen apps requesting permissions through FB app first,  then posting through Feed Dialog.

Comment: Dear Christine, thank you for your respond. I have made changes as you recommended, used Share Dialog and added fallback to iOS 6 Share Sheet (in case when user don't have fb app installed on his phone). But the problem is that I want to deploy my application both to iOS5 and iOS6 users, so this solution won't work for those who have iOS5 and don't have fb application. To my opinion the best and most flexible way is feed dialog, but by now I still have a problem discribed above.

Comment: I must also thank you for this project https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.5-howtos/tree/master/ShareHowTo/Complete, it helped me a lot and I forgot to tell that one of the major conditions is not to made user to login every time when he needs to publish this is my main goal...